# Display array of images on a certain amount of tableview cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an `UIImageView` inside my table view cell, named pic. I want to use an array named `colors` (filled with `UIImage`s), to display on 3 tableview cells.

I have the `ViewController` class and the tableview cell class listed below. The tableview displays the imageview pic. I assume you would place the color array in `cellForRowAt` method.

```
import UIKit
    
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    var colors:[UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "blue")!,
        UIImage(named: "red")!,
        UIImage(named: "red")!
    ]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 118
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customtv
        return cell
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            
    }    
}
    
class customtv: UITableViewCell {
    lazy var backView : UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: self.frame.width  , height: 110))
         view.backgroundColor = .green
            
        return view
    }()

    lazy var pic : UIImageview = {
        let view = UIImageview(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 6, width: 100  , height: 100))
        view.backgroundColor = .red
            
        return view
    }()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        backView.clipsToBounds = true
        backView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 6, width: bounds.maxX  , height: 110)
    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(animated, animated: true)
        addSubview(backView)
        addSubview(pic)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this example below

```
import UIKit

class ViewController1: UIViewController {
    var tableView: UITableView?
    
    var colors:[UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "blue")!,
        UIImage(named: "red")!,
        UIImage(named: "red")!
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadUI()
    }
    
    func loadUI()  {
        tableView = UITableView()
        self.view.addSubview(tableView.unsafelyUnwrapped)
        tableView?.register(CustomTVC.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView?.delegate=self
        tableView?.dataSource=self
        tableView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView?.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

extension ViewController1: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 118
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTVC
        cell.pic.image = colors[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

class CustomTVC: UITableViewCell {
    lazy var backView : UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var pic : UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        commonInit()
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        backView.clipsToBounds = true
        backView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 6, width: bounds.maxX  , height: 110)
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        contentView.addSubview(backView)
        backView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
        backView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
        backView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
        backView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
        
        backView.addSubview(pic)
        pic.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pic.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backView.topAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
        pic.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backView.leftAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
        pic.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
        pic.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pic.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(animated, animated: true)
    }
}
```